# Interfacing with MainActivity from video player

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm new to android app development and just creating a simple application for my workplace that allows video playback control from a web panel, so the app pings the panel on a loop and if it gets a request to play a video, it plays it. If it gets a request to stop the video or play something else, then it does that.

From MainActivity I'm using startActivity to start an instance of ExoPlayer, I know how to pass variables to the activity, but how do I send information the other way or control the playback? Basically that loop that runs constantly to check for new actions is running in MainActivity, once the player is started I have no ability to stop playback, get stream metrics or do anything with that instance at all. I realise I'm probably doing things backwards and should have a background service do the checks, but I still have no idea how to pass information back and forth.

Does anyone have any tips or suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two activities, you have to use an acitivty (the main) and a fragment (the video player). Then define a callback interface which will implement the activity and thus manage the communication between fragment and activity

See this https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments/